# Drawing custom NSWindow from images

Tags: subclass, nswindow

I've got some images (4 corners, a title bar (+ close button), a bottom bar and a fill) to make an NSWindow from. But I have no idea what to write in the `drawRect:` method to make it into an NSWindow. Where should I start?